# Broken OnePlus One - Data recovery possible?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode

So I've got a OnePlus One that's been badly smashed up (no screen or digitizer), and I was wondering if there's any hope of trying to rescue some (or even all) of the data off it?

Some details:

1 - The device still switches on

2 - It's running the latest version of Cyanogen OS (I think 13.1.12)

3 - It's still recognized by my PC when I connect it via USB. (I can't retrieve any data from it because of that annoying thing where you first have to give it permission when you plug it in)

4 - USB Debugging wasn't enabled, so ADB isn't picking it up either.

Any help/advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I have a couple questions first, and then I will provide answers.

Did you ever use a service such as Google Photos to back up photos?

If you have Verizon, did Verizon Cloud back them up?

If none of your data was backed up, I'm not sure if you can save your photos, but you should be able to restore your apps when you get a new phone. If you visit the [Google My Activity](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols) page, and scroll down to Device Information, it should be checked. If it isn't, try checking it, and it should be able to back up if the device still turns on.

This backs up your apps, and if you buy a new Android phone and login with the same account, it should ask if you want to restore your apps from a backup. I'm really sorry about your phone, and I know this is not a great solution, but it was the best I could come up with.

In the future, however, consider an app like Google Drive, Google Photos, or OneDrive for backing up photos on WiFi. I recommend [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos), as they give free unlimited storage and have awesome categorization features. Anyway, I hope my answer helped and I hope you can get a new phone.